# Show that if p is an odd prime dividing Φd(a) then either p|d or p≡1 mod d."

Tags: number-theory

Let a ∈ Z, d ∈ N. Consider the dth cyclotomic polynomial, Φ<sub>d</sub>(x). Show that if p is an odd prime dividing Φ<sub>d</sub>(a) then either $p|d$ or $p ≡ 1$ mod d."

I am given the solution below; but my question is, how does showing $D=d$, and the order of a mod p is d, prove that what we need to show, that "either $p|d$ or $p ≡ 1$ mod d"? I am not sure I follow the general proof strategy here.

---

Here is the solution:
Suppose p does not divide d. Since Φ<sub>d</sub>(x)|(x<sup>d</sup> − 1), $$Φ_d(a) ≡ 0 \mathrm{\;mod\;p} ⇒ a^d − 1 ≡ 0 \mathrm {\;mod\;p}$$ so a is coprime to p and the order of a mod p is a divisor of d.

Now suppose that the order of a mod p is a divisor, D of d, with $D < d$.

Then  \begin{equation*} a^D-1 =
\prod_{e|D}
Φ_e(a) ≡ 0 \mathrm {\;mod\;p}
\end{equation*}
.
So there exists $e|D$ such that $Φ_e(a) ≡ 0$ mod p, and $e < d$ since $e|D$ and $D < d$ by assumption. It follows that a is a root of
\begin{equation*} x^d − 1 =
\prod_{f|d}  Φ_f(a) ≡ 0 \mathrm {\;mod\;p}
\end{equation*}

with multiplicity at least 2, i.e. that $$x^d − 1 ≡ (x − a)^2 \cdot f(x) \mathrm {\;mod\;p}$$ for some polynomial f(x) ∈ Z[x].
But this is impossible, since after taking derivatives, we would get that a must also be a root of $dx^d$ mod p , but $da^d \not\equiv 0$ mod p, since p does not divide d and p does not divide a.
So $D = d$ and hence the order of a mod p is exactly d.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Shaun great resource thanks :)

Comment: Avoid the use of $*$ yo denote multiplication. That's a practice from programming, but this is a math forum. Use `x \cdot y` for $x\cdot y$, `x \times y` for $x\times y$ or simple juxtaposition.

Comment: @jjagmath updated again, thanks. Much appreciation also if you could help with my question!

Comment: Closely related: [Prime Factors of Cyclotomic Polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/538707/prime-factors-of-cyclotomic-polynomials) from 2013.